# How do I click on the the github avatar when forking using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I'm using [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example) to try to click through forking and cloning a repo. However, I'm not able to click on the avatar to take me to my forked repo (see image) 
[image]

I tried using the [Selenium IDE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/) to generate the required ruby commands but I'm bottling necking when it comes to actually clicking on the avatar. I think it might be because I need to pause to wait for it to load but I'm not sure. Below is the ruby rspec code that I generated from the IDE and then my ruby code that I've tried to write using the rspec as a guide. Also attached is the error message when trying the last test (other tests are commented out).

What am I missing here? How do I click the avatar when the repo has already been forked?

Thanks for your help :)

ruby code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
# driver.get "https://github.com/login"
base_url = "https://github.com/"

driver.get(base_url + "/login")
driver.find_element(:id, "login_field").clear
driver.find_element(:id, "login_field").send_keys "mbigras"
driver.find_element(:id, "password").clear
driver.find_element(:id, "password").send_keys "xxxx"
driver.find_element(:name, "commit").click

driver.get "https://github.com/sf-golden-bears-2016/sql-voting-results-retrieving-data-challenge"
# driver.get "https://github.com/sf-golden-bears-2016/database-drill-sqlite-shell-part-1-challenge"
driver.find_element(:link, "Fork").click
# <img alt="@mbigras" class="avatar owner-select-avatar" height="100" src="https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/5590632?v=3&amp;s=200" width="100">
# driver.find_element(:alt, "@mbigras").click
# driver.find_elements(:class_name, "avatar owner-select-avatar" )
# driver.find_elements(:class_name, "avatar" )
expect(driver).to have_selector 'img.avatar.owner-select-avatar'
# driver.find_element(:name, "organization").click
driver.find_element(:css, "img.avatar.owner-select-avatar")
driver.find_element(:xpath, "(//button[type='button'])[3]").click
driver.find_element(:xpath, "(//button[type='button'])[4]").click

# login_field = driver.find_element :id => "login_field"
# driver.type(login_field, "mbigras")

input = gets.chomp
driver.quit
```

rspec generated by ide:

```
require "json"
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "rspec"
include RSpec::Expectations

describe "SqlVotingOld" do

  before(:each) do
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    @base_url = "https://github.com/"
    @accept_next_alert = true
    @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
    @verification_errors = []
  end

  after(:each) do
    @driver.quit
    @verification_errors.should == []
  end

  it "test_sql_voting_old" do
    @driver.get(@base_url + "/login")
    @driver.find_element(:id, "login_field").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "login_field").send_keys "mbigras"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "password").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "password").send_keys "xxxx"
    @driver.find_element(:name, "commit").click
    @driver.find_element(:link, "Fork").click
    @driver.find_element(:css, "img.avatar.owner-select-avatar").click
    @driver.find_element(:xpath, "(//button[@type='button'])[3]").click
    @driver.find_element(:xpath, "(//button[@type='button'])[4]").click
  end

  def element_present?(how, what)
    ${receiver}.find_element(how, what)
    true
  rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
    false
  end

  def alert_present?()
    ${receiver}.switch_to.alert
    true
  rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoAlertPresentError
    false
  end

  def verify(&blk)
    yield
  rescue ExpectationNotMetError => ex
    @verification_errors << ex
  end

  def close_alert_and_get_its_text(how, what)
    alert = ${receiver}.switch_to().alert()
    alert_text = alert.text
    if (@accept_next_alert) then
      alert.accept()
    else
      alert.dismiss()
    end
    alert_text
  ensure
    @accept_next_alert = true
  end
end
```

error message:

```
/Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:70:in `assert_ok': no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"img.avatar.owner-select-avatar"} (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError)
  (Session info: chrome=51.0.2704.103)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397929 (fb72fb249a903a0b1041ea71eb4c8b3fa0d9be5a),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.5 x86_64)
    from /Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:34:in `initialize'
    from /Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `new'
    from /Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `create_response'
    from /Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:90:in `request'
    from /Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
    from /Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:649:in `raw_execute'
    from /Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:627:in `execute'
    from /Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:596:in `find_element_by'
    from /Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/search_context.rb:61:in `find_element'
    from login-using-ide.rb:21:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Though it doesn't answer your question, have you looked at `hub` cli tool? It might be able to do this.

Comment: Big hug for you :)

Comment: no problem. Regarding your Selenium attempt, there is `Selenium::WebDriver::Wait` - see [here](https://gist.github.com/kenrett/7553278) for examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browse through [hub cli tool](https://github.com/github/hub/blob/master/man/hub.1.ronn) as recommended by @maxpleaner